# Get the string using regex after the matching words?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I have one string :

```js
function test(){
  var datas = "http://localhost/test/test.html?src=www.123@gmail.com(testing)";
  var spl = datas.match(/[^src=]?\b*/g);
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = spl;
  }
test();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I Need ah whole string after the `src=` string match.i need a answer like `www.123@gmail.com(testing)` .please help me ...correct my code

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a regular expression to do that. But this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way of doing it. you should definitely need to lookup for some online tutorials on using regular expressions.

```
  var datas = "http://localhost/test/test.html?src=www.123@gmail.com(testing)";
  var m1 = datas.match(/[&?]src=([^&]+)/);
  var spl = "notfound";
  if (m1 && m1.length>1) spl=m1[1];
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = spl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression [capturing groups](http://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) and [exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/RegExp/exec) function from JavaScript RegExp prototype.

For example, following code will extract everything after the first occurrence of `src=` or return `null` if provided string doesn't match.

```
function extract(str) {
  var regex = /^(?:.*src=)(.*)$/i;
  return regex.test(str) ? /^(?:.*src=)(.*)$/i.exec(str)[1] : null;
}

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = extract('http://localhost/test/test.html?src=www.123@gmail.com(testing)');
```

Check the explanation of this regular expression and test on different strings at https://regex101.com/r/zW1lK8/1